# Operand should have 1 column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm getting the error "operand should be contain 1 column".

Yes, I try to compare 1 column with 3, so is what I want to achieve possible?

Clear exemple: I have a table test

```
 id   profile_id  result_number
 10     1232        3
 10     3263        5
 10     2222        4
 10     2321        1
```

Actually, I have 3 query and I want to get all in one query.  First, I get the result number of profile_id 2222 (return 4)

```
 SELECT `result_number` FROM test WHERE id=10 AND `profile_id`=2222
```

Next, I get the profile_id who have result_number - 1

```
SELECT `profile_id` FROM test
 WHERE id=10 AND `result_number` = 4 - 1
```

(return 3)

Finally, I get the profile_id who have result_number + 1

```
SELECT `profile_id` FROM test WHERE id=10 AND `result_number` = 4 + 1
```

(return 5)

result expected :

```
profile_id
    3263
    2222
    1232
```

Is it possible to achieve it?

Comment: What's the query that gives you the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `JOIN` a subquery if it contains multiple rows:

```
SELECT profile_id
FROM test t, (
  SELECT result_number
  FROM test
  WHERE id = 10
  AND profile_id = 2222
) q
WHERE t.result_number BETWEEN q.result_number-1 AND q.result_number+1
AND id = 10
ORDER BY t.result_number DESC
```

DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b922/1

Answer (score 0):

```
with a  as
(
SELECT `result_number`, profile_id FROM test WHERE id=10 AND `profile_id`=2222
)

SELECT PROFILE_ID FROM A
UNION
SELECT B.PROFILE_ID FROM TEST AS B, A WHERE B.RESULT_NUMBER = (A.RESULT_NUMBER - 1)
UNION
SELECT C.PROFILE_ID FROM TEST AS C, A WHERE C.RESULT_NUMBER = (A.RESULT_NUMBER + 1)
```

Comment: Yeah, I am wrong to overlook that MYSQL tag. MYSQL does not have WITH Clause. Your answer above that uses BETWEEN is right.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do what you want:

```
select *
from test 
where id=10 and ( result_number= 4 or result_number=4-1 or result_number = 4+1)
```

Comment: The problem is the `4` is from another query.  He wants to combine that query into this one.

Comment: exacly, at first stage i don't know result number = 4    . I'm pretty sure there's a solution somewhere..:)

Comment: Oooh.. so the @RocketHazmat answer will fit your problem.